# Text box size issue for IE

Tags: css, html

IE Issue With Input Box Size.
I created HTML and same HTML working fine. When I put same HTML in VF component it's working fine for Firefox & Chrome but for IE, text feedback box size shrinking too much.
..

```
<a href="#" onclick="ResetFeedbackForm('feedbackPopup');"><img src="{!URLFOR($Resource.Wirestone,'Images/Tile_Images/CP3_X.png')}" style="float:right;"/></a>
                          <table width="100%" height="100%">
                          <tbody>
                            <tr ><td colspan="2" align="center"><apex:outputLabel styleclass="page-title">{!SubmitFeedbackLabel}</apex:outputLabel></td></tr>
                           <tr height="70%"><td colspan="2"><textarea class="textfeedback" id="feedbackText" style="height:70%" onmousemove="ToggleFeedbackSubmit()" onkeyup="ToggleFeedbackSubmit()"></textarea></td></tr>                          

                           <tr >
                                <td align="center"><input type="button" id="feedbackSubmit" value="{!submitLabel}" class="btn-gray btn-gray-small text-gray" disabled="true" onclick="SubmitFeedback()"/></td>
                                <td align="center"><input type="button" id="feedbackSubmit" value="{!cancelLabel}" class="btn-gray btn-gray-small text-white" onclick="ResetFeedbackForm('feedbackPopup')"/></td>
                            </tr>
                            </tbody>    
                          </table>
```

CSS Style:

```
.textfeedback
{
    width:100%;
    height:70%;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    resize:none;

}
```

Comment: Is this a Salesforce specific issue or more of a general HTML/CSS question? A more general question would be better suited to Stackoverflow.com

Comment: asking the same question over doesn't help. Please improve your original question or consider asking the html specific part on stackoverflow.com, or non salesforce specific "mother site"

Comment: Go to F12 Developer tools > Document mode > Quirks
When changing mode Quirks. It’s working fine as expected.
..